# $.fancybox is not a function (fancybox pop up ajax response)

Tags: jquery, ajax, server-response

I want to pop up the ajax response by fancybox, I saw the network section in console, the response is ok. But I am getting $.fancybox is not a function.
thanks in advance!

```
$("#mysubmit").click(function(){
 var myvar = {
"secure_key":"41561541561561","username":$("#username").val(),"password" :$("#password").val()};

$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/ajaxtest.php",
    async: false,
    data: myvar,
    success: (function (response) {
        var result =
            "<div id='result'>" +
            "<p>" + response + "</p>" +
            "</div>";
        //$.facybox is not a function HERE
        $.fancybox(result, {
            type: "html",
        }); // show formated response
      })
   })

});
```

Comment: Did you add fancybox.min.js file? I think your fancybox js isn't loaded.

Comment: of course!!! and it's is working on my page, but not is this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FancyBox has to be instanciated on an element.
You actually try to instanciate it on jQuery...

Try this:

```
success: (function (response) {
  var result =
    "<div id='result'>" +
    "<p>" + response + "</p>" +
    "</div>";

  $("body").append( $(result) );

  $(document).find("#result").fancybox(); // show formated response
})
```

Comment: but in this way it will not close!

Comment: Add some options (I didn't)... See [here](http://fancybox.net/howto) for an example (at the bottom) and [here](http://fancybox.net/api) for the complete option list.

Answer (score 0):

in case if anyone searching for the same problem, here is the solution:

```
$("#mysubmit").click(function(){
var myvar = {
"secure_key":"41561541561561","username":$("#username").val(),"password" :$("#password").val()};

 $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/ajaxtest.php",
    async: false,
    data: myvar,
    success: (function (response) {
      var result =
        "<div id='result' style='display: none;'>" +
        "<p>" + response + "</p>" +
        "<a class='btn' data-fancybox-close=''>OK!</a>"+
        "</div>";

      $("body").append(result);
    })
})

});
```

and then I added the #result as a data-scr to  tag, works perfectly.

```
<a data-fancybox type="Submit" id="mysubmit" class="btn" data-src="#result" >Submit </a>
```

Comment: according to what Mr @Louys Patrice Bessette taught me.